# Freight shipping rates not showing up when country is changed in magento 1.9

Tags: magento, fedex

When we change the country to Mexico, it gives us the error:  "This shipping method is currently unavailable. If you would like to ship using this shipping method, please contact us."  It all works fine on US country, since the store is located here. We suppose it should shows International Economy Freight rate.[This is how the error msg shows on frontend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eEv3S.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things:

> Make sure the shipping method is available in Mexico ( or that region of Mexico )

Login to your Fedex.com account, type in those address details into the Fedex rate checker and see what services are available for that area.

> If you don't have the method available, contact your Fedex account manager, they may need to enable it.

If you intend to use this service / method often you should negociate preferred rates with Fedex.